# add css classes into media image in wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, image, class

I used an image in my 4000 post wordpress. Now I need to add custom classes or ID into that image, so I can use it when I create CSS rules. Can I add Classes through image media? Or there is another option to do that?

[Thats the image that I need to add classes or ID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/opgJp.png)

Comment: can you change questions with the image where you would like to show a class or something code you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

You can use "get_image_tag_class" for this:

```
function add_custom_class($class) {
    $class .= ' some_class_name_here';
    return $class;
}
add_filter('get_image_tag_class', 'add_custom_class' );
```

Comment: Where do I need to put that code? Now the image that I mention above doesnt have any class or ID.

Comment: You need to put that to functions.php of your theme.

Comment: Hi, I dont think that can solved my problem. Is that function use to select image with some class and add another custom class? The thing is, my image that I want to add custom class doesnt have class or ID, so how can I select the image?

Comment: It will be better if you give some URL with that image.